# CSS positioning with page reference

Tags: css, positioning, center

Simple question, how do I position an item with an entire page reference ?

In my case, i got in my header a floating image, and then 2 sets of title. When i use:

```
text-align: center;
```

It asign itself using the place beetween the image's width end and the rest of the page. How do I align it using the page center reference ?

Have a look (sorry <10 reputation): https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qGqw.jpg

Here, all links like : Staff, Apps.. are center positioning with the entire page. But the NCAPP isnt.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Unless something is positioned absolutely, it will be affected by the elements around it which take up width. If you provide your HTML and CSS in a demo we might be able to help further

Comment: To piggy back off of Paulie_D, on casual inspection it seems the NCAPP is being affected by the AIPS element. To fix this, remove the AIPS element from the page flow with something like `position:absolute` and the NCAPP element should stretch to 100% width.

Answer (score -1):

to align it to the page you would need to position it absolutely, then it will position itself relative to the nearest relatively positioned element

to center it you can use this css

```
.centered-div {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for. Your code will cause the child to completely cover the relatively positioned element..

Comment: not if the child object has a width and height set, in this case it would centre, but cover only what it covers with it's own width and height. afaik this is the only way the positioning could be done

Comment: True but the code above doesn't have any height and width set.  You could try this - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/RNxypP